# store temp variables in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have some cypher queries that I execute against my neo4j database. The query is in this form

```
MATCH p=(j:JOB)-[r:HAS|STARTS]->(s:URL)-[r1:VISITED]->(t:URL) 
WHERE j.job_id =5000 and r1.origin='iframe' and r1.job_id=5000 AND NOT (t.netloc =~ 'VERY_LONG_LIST')   
RETURN count(r1) AS number_iframes;
```

If you can't understand what I am doing. This is a much simpler query

```
MATCH (s:WORD)
WHERE NOT (s.text=~"badword1|badword2|badword3")
RETURN s
```

I am basically trying to match some words against specific list

The problem is that this list is very large as you can see my job_id=5000  and I have more than 20000 jobs, so if my whitelist length is 1MB then I will end up with very large queries. I tried 500 jobs and end up with 200 MB queries file.

I was trying to execute these queries using [transactions](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#transactions) from [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0) but this is wont be feasible because my post request length will be very large and it will timeout. As a result, I though of using

```
neo4j-shell -file <queries_file>
```

However as you can see the file size is very large because of the large whitelist. So my question is there anyway that I can store this "whitelist" in a variable in neo4j using cypher?? 
I wish if there is something similar to this

```
SAVE $whitelist="word1,word2,word3,word4,word5...."

MATCH p=(j:JOB)-[r:HAS|STARTS]->(s:URL)-[r1:VISITED]->(t:URL) 
    WHERE j.job_id =5000 and r1.origin='iframe' and r1.job_id=5000 AND NOT (t.netloc =~ $whitelist) 
    RETURN count(r1) AS number_iframes;
```

Answer (score 1):

What datatype is your netloc?

If you have an index on netloc you can also use `t.netloc IN {list}` where {list} is a parameter provided from the outside.

Such large regular expressions **will not be fast**
What exactly is your regexp and netloc format like? Perhaps you can change that into a split + index-list lookup?

In general also for regexps you can provide an outside parameter.

You can also use "IN" + index for job_ids.

You can also run a separate job that tags the jobs within your whitelist with a label and use that label for additional filtering e.g. in the match already.

Why do you have to check this twice ? Isn't it enough that the job has id=5000?

`j.job_id =5000 and r1.job_id=5000`

Comment: I don't have an index on netloc but I can create one (in other words what might stop me fro having an index). the netloc is basically a FQDN value something like www.google.com, www.yahoo.com.
I can use `t.netloc IN {list}` but I still have the same large query which means I can not send a lot of queries to the REST API.

Comment: I check twice because I can have the following scenario 
`(j1)-->(www.example1.com)--> (google.com)-->(google.com/jquery.js)` AND 
`(j2)-->(www.example2.com)--> (google.com)-->(google.com/jquery.js)`
when I do my MATCH  at j1 it starts from the j1 JOB node but when it reaches google node it shows all relations between google and google.com/jquery.js which I do NOT want. I only want the relation between google and jquery when the starting node is j1. got me?

Comment: Is there any idea to have portable output document from running neo4j-shell -f <queries file> ??

Comment: One reason why I use regular expression than list is that I want to exclude all subdomains .. for example if I have s2.google.com as one of the URL nodes but I have google.com in my whitelist then it will be excluded cause I match on .*\.google.com. I can NOT do this behaviour if it was a simple list

Comment: what do you meant by portable output doucment?

Comment: I know what you want to do, perhaps it is better to add an additional property with the base-domain? and index that property?

Comment: Yes adding a property to with these base domains is the best idea. I think it will work the best. By  portable document, I mean something like JSON file or XML so I can parse it directly!! Rather than the normal output of neo4jshell.

Comment: Michele can't you edit your answer and add your last comment about the additional property so I can mark it as a valid answer for my question